# Validações de Strings

Tags: java, jquery, string

Andei pesquisando como validar e-mail, datas, horas etc. E no caso do e-mail, encontrei um código como este: `/^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;`. Ele está incompleto. Mas queria entender o que são esses símbolos, e o que eles representam para fazer a validação de uma string?

Se alguém puder esclarecer como isso funciona eu agradeço.

Comment: Olá tudo joia? se tratam de expressões regulares e em programação ajudam muito inclusive se tem livros escritos somente para esse tipo de conteúdo, acredito que significa excessão a barra depois pode se colocar qualquer caractere seguido de arroba e logo depois segue de qualquer cacatere e depois se tem uma lista com dois caractere e por fim finaliza, se esqueci ou errei alguma coisa peço desculpas fiz rapidinho de cabeça. segue um link de conceitos básicos de expressões regulares: http://www.devmedia.com.br/conceitos-basicos-sobre-expressoes-regulares-em-java/27539

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A explicação dessa regex é assim:

> `/^.+@.+\..{2,}$/`

- `/` - simbolo de abertura do objeto regex.
- `^` - indica inicio da string
- `.+` - qualquer carater menos mudança de linha, uma ou mais ocorrências
- `@` - um caracter "arroba"
- `\.` - o caracter ponto, escapado porque em regex o ponto tem uma funcionalidade, assim com `\` quer dizer o proprio caracter ponto e não a função que ele costuma ter em regex
- `.{2,}` - qualquer caracter menos mudança de linha, dois seguidos ou mais
- `$` - final da string
- `/` - fecho do objeto regex

Há um site muito bom para analizar regex, dá uma olhada aqui: https://regex101.com/r/tP8yC9/1

Comment: E essas expressões regulares é um padrão para todas as linguagens? É a mesma coisa no java e no jquery ou javascript?

Comment: @Vynstus na grande maioria sim. Creio que o teu exemplo funciona bem noutras linguagens. No link que passei na resposta podes mudar linguagem na barra da esquerda. Podes também dar uma olhada aqui: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines

Comment: @Vynstus a resposta era o que procuravas?

Comment: Sim, desculpe a demora. Obrigado.